# Documentation outdated for form recognizer?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

The documentation for the containerized form recognizer refers to the cognitive-services-recognize-text:latest but the link provided goes to cognitive-services-read:latest. Which one is the correct recognize text container?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/form-recognizer-container-howto

Answer (score 0):

The "Recognize-Text" API is being deprecated (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text#recognize-text-api?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)) and replaced by "Read" (Batch Read) API.

So I guess you are pointing to the right container but Form Recognizer's documentation is outdated yes.

You can edit the doc and submit a PR to fix it. It will be validated by people on Microsoft's side